# No such package after catkin_make

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Noetic on a Raspberry Pi 4 with basic ROS com setup (no rviz, etc). Following the tutorial I run

```
$ catkin_create_pkg picar std_msgs rospy roscpp
$ cd ~/ros_catkin/ws
$ catkin_make
```

Sorry I don't have enough points to upload a screenshot of the console. This is an empty package with no added code yet but my understanding is that it should still compile. I ran catkin_make and then the second time I did a whitelist to just compile the picar package. I see the folder and get no error message from catkin_make but roscd and rospack both don't see it and I get No Such Package errors. Am I missing a step?

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'picar'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(picar)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build"
####
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ rospack depends1 picar
[rospack] Error: no such package picar
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ roscd picar
roscd: No such package/stack 'picar'
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ ls
build  build_isolated  devel  devel_isolated  noetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall  src
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ cd src
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/src $ ls
catkin        CMakeLists.txt  gencpp  genlisp  gennodejs  message_generation  picar      ros       ros_comm_msgs  roscpp_core      roslisp  std_msgs
class_loader  cmake_modules   geneus  genmsg   genpy      message_runtime     pluginlib  ros_comm  rosconsole     ros_environment  rospack
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/src $ cd picar
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/src/picar $ ls
CMakeLists.txt  include  package.xml  src
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/src/picar $ cd ..
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/src $ cd ..
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ ls
build  build_isolated  devel  devel_isolated  noetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall  src
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ cd build
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/build $ ls
atomic_configure  catkin_make.cache  cmake_install.cmake     CTestTestfile.cmake  genmsg     Makefile            pluginlib      rosconsole       rospack
catkin            class_loader       cmake_modules           gencpp               gennodejs  message_generation  ros            roscpp_core      std_msgs
catkin_generated  CMakeCache.txt     CTestConfiguration.ini  geneus               genpy      message_runtime     ros_comm       ros_environment  test_results
CATKIN_IGNORE     CMakeFiles         CTestCustom.cmake       genlisp              gtest      picar               ros_comm_msgs  roslisp
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/build $ cd picar
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/build/picar $ ls
catkin_generated  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  CTestTestfile.cmake  Makefile
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws/build/picar $
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361870/no-such-package-after-catkin_make/) by [cjonesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/59697/cjonesy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-19**:\

> Sorry I don't have enough points to upload a screenshot of the console

Good. You shouldn't post screenshots of terminals, so not being able to do that is actually not that much of a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you clarify whether you've ran a `source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` between running `catkin_make` and your first `rospack` command? If you didn't, that would most likely explain why your package cannot be found (it's not on any search path known to `rospack` in that case).

Also: you appear to be mixing a `catkin_make_isolated` and a regular `catkin_make` workspace.

I would recommend you try to avoid that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cjonesy](https://answers.ros.org/users/59697/cjonesy/) on 2020-09-19**:
Yes, the issue was setup.bash. I have that resolved now. On to new error messages! Trying to put together some course curriculum for a Masters CS IoT course that will potentially use ROS in it.